# iphone : FBConnect Auto post to user wall

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fbconnect

i want to auto post to a user wall from my iphone applications ( without that "publish" "skip" dialog box ). how i can do that ?

Comment: Please look through the edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following should be called in the class that implements `FBSessionDelegate` and `FBRequestDelegate`:

```
Facebook *_facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId];
NSArray *_permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           @"read_stream", @"offline_access",nil] retain];
[_facebook authorize:_permissions delegate:self];
```

And that is the call for fb post (should be used in the same class):

```
NSString *message = @"This is the message I want to post";
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               message, @"message",
                               nil];

[_facebook requestWithMethodName:@"stream.publish"
                       andParams:params
                   andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                     andDelegate:self];
```

If you want to post a message on the wall of other user you should include "uid" parameter in your params dictionary. Please consult http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/

*P.S. There are all the necessary examples in the [iPhone Facebook connect SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) sample code, so please **do not afraid to investigate just a little bit** ;)*

Comment: hey dude, i tried to run this code but i only get an exception: +[FBRequest request]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x14994 --> do you have an idea?

Comment: Please look carefully through the answer. I've mentioned that you have  to resume or create `FBSession`, did you do that? See my edits: I've empahsized this frase and added the code that creates `FBSession` so please review your code.

Comment: @NR4TR i think the issue is you're using an old iOS library

Comment: Enjoy the correct answer. This is just a code from Facebook DemoApp + a little bit roaming around http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/#publishing-methods to find `stream.publish` description. I've mentioned both of them before. And now I'm confused, was my previous answer really worth of downvoting? Or it is just frustration on the grounds of laziness? ;)

Comment: @NR4TR Good job! I came back to this to edit your answer, but you did it anyway!

Comment: @NR4TR: I am also getting unrecognized selector send to class" exception. I have posted question with full code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002229/iphone-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-exception-while-publishing-stream Could you please check what's wrong there? I have taken care everything!